# Skipping of tests in pytest using the command line

Tags: django, pytest

I've tried to skip tests in pytest according to this: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option

When I try to run the tests using only the command `pytest`, the marked tests are skipped as intended. But when I run the tests with `pytest --runslow` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --runslow
  inifile: /app/pyproject.toml
  rootdir: /app
```

My tests are in `project/myapp/tests/tests.py` and the conftest file in `project/conftest.py`.
How can I make pytest recognized my command line argument?

Comment: Did you use the example you linked to? What does your `conftest.py` look like?

Comment: I see that your project is in the `project` folder, but `pytest` reports an `/app` rootdir folder. Possibly you are calling pytest in the wrong place. Please add more info about the environment you are running pytest in.

Comment: The project is dockerized, that's why the error shows /app.

Comment: `conftest.py` is identical to the example

Comment: Try and move `conftest.py` one or two directories up, into `myapp/tests/`. After all, pytest will look for a `tests` directory.

Comment: Yes, that did it! Thanks. I thought it was something with pyproject.toml, but it was only the conftest location.

Comment: Are you skipping tests because they are slow, or do you just want to skip specific tests?

Comment: Just want to skip specific tests, that we can only run when connected to a network